# Array reduce method is overwriting the first element

Tags: javascript

below is my function which have reduce method

```
    getFilters(gridFilters, columnList){
      const filtersArray = [];
      let filterObject = {};
      gridFilters.forEach((ele, i, arr) => {
        filtersArray.push(...arr[i].filters);
      });      
      const _filArr = filtersArray.reduce((acc, {field, operator, value}) => {        
        filterObject['columnName'] = field;   
        filterObject['filterValue1'] = value;
        filterObject['filterOperator1'] = operator;
        filterObject['filterValue2'] = '';
        filterObject['filterOperator2'] = ''; 
        columnList.push(filterObject);    
        return acc;
      }, {});    
      return columnList;
```

Here, `filtersArray` will have 2 array elements like'

```
    Array(2)    
    0:
        field: "objectType"
        operator: "contains"
        value: "lic"
        [[Prototype]]: Object
    1:
        field: "attributeDisplayName"
        operator: "contains"
        value: "date"
        [[Prototype]]: Object
        length: 2
        [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

But after pushing the values to the `columnList` array, I am seeing the second object (which has `attributeDisplayName`) is coming for both values. Basically the first object (which has `objectType`) is getting overwritten with second object in array.

This is how the `columnList` is getting overwritten

```
    Array(2)    
    0:
        columnName: "attributeDisplayName"
        filterOperator1: "contains"
        filterOperator2: ""
        filterValue1: "date"
        filterValue2: ""
        [[Prototype]]: Object
    1:
        columnName: "attributeDisplayName"
        filterOperator1: "contains"
        filterOperator2: ""
        filterValue1: "date"
        filterValue2: ""
        [[Prototype]]: Object
        length: 2
        [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Can some one please suggest what I am doing wrong here. Thanks

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: `filterObject` is always the same object. You keep modifying it in the loop. Just create a new one each loop.

Comment: not `reduce` anything, use `map` or `forEach` will do

Comment: If you're never using `_filArr`, you're misusing `reduce` to replace a simple `forEach`.